# Call Ajax function from Link in jsp [a href= onclick=""]

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am trying to call an Ajax function using onclick attribute of `<a href>` tag in Jsp. I am new to Ajax.

Here is my Jsp code from where I am calling Ajax method

```
String servername="";
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
        servername=itr.next();
           <a href="#" onclick="makeRequest(serverName)"> 
    <% out.println(servername);%>
    </a>
}
```

And here is my Ajax code:

```
function makeRequest(a) {

    var xmlHttpRequest = getXMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = getReadyStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest);
    xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "ChannelList?serverName="+a, true);
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttpRequest.send(null);
}
```

Now what I need to do is to get serverName value in Ajax `method:makeRequest()`, so that I can pass it further.

Most important thing - I need to take that value of serverName, which is selected by user by click on link.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
function makeRequest(a) {

    var xmlHttpRequest = getXMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "ChannelList?serverName="+a, true);
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState==4 && xmlHttpRequest.status==200) {
            alert(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlHttpRequest.send();
}
```

Comment: I already call this function.look into my code,function name is getReadyStateHandler()....

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code review and bug fixing forum but a FAQ board. This answer is correct.